# How to fetch only the array from the form elements javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I used like this

```js
var fData = $('.my_form').serializeArray();
console.log(fData)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<form class="my_form">
<input type="hidden" name="library[0][]" value="3">
<input type="hidden" name="library[0][]" value="5">
<input type="hidden" name="time" value="2:30PM">
<input type="hidden" name="bookname" value="space mission">
<input type="hidden" name="library[1][]" value="8">
<input type="hidden" name="detail_days[0][]" value="3">
</form>
```

which was my `formdata`, which contains all the form inputs done by the user.

the output of serializeArray will look like this

1. name: 'library[0][] ',value : '3'
2. name: 'library[0][] ',value : '5'
3. name: 'time' , value: '2:30 PM'
4. name: 'bookname', value: 'space mission'
5. name: 'library[1][] ',value : '8'
6. name: 'detail_days[0][]', value: '3'
   .
   .

like this, i need only library array alone from it, how to fetch it?

library = >{ '0' =>{'3','5'}, '1' =>{'8','10'}
like this i need to access this specific array alone

is there anything like serializeArray, forgetting only the specific array

Answer (score 0):

You can use `serializeArray()` on a collection of form controls, not the whole form. So

```
$(".my_form [name^=library]").serializeArray()
```

This just selects the elements whose names start with `library`.

Comment: Doesn't zip up the values unfortunately

Comment: @Barmar how to zipup it

Comment: What do you mean by zip?

Comment: `serialize()` and `serializeArray()` are designed for sending form data to a server. They're not general purpose array creation utilities.

Comment: @Barmar how to convert the array in the format like library[][] ={ '0' =>{ '1', '2'}} like that